# how to manage checkbox in django template

Tags: django, templates

This code is checking all the courses. and if i uncheck only one item then it is not performing any action. I want only the selected items to be checked.How can i do that

> html template

```
    <div class="form-group">
               <h5>Courses <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
               <div class="controls">
                 {% for course in courses %}
                 <input name ="courses" type="checkbox" id="{{course.title}}" required value="{{course.title}}"
                {% if course.title %}checked="checked" {% endif %}>
                 <label for="{{course.title}}">{{course.title}}</label>
                 {% endfor %}
               </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your boxes are all checked because you wrote `{% if course.title %}checked="checked" {% endif %}`. This code means that if a course has a title, which I'm assuming they all do, they will be *checked*. It is better to not include this `if` condition (assuming you don't need any checkboxes pre-checked), and also use a more unique identifier other than `title` (which two courses could potentially share).

```
<div class="form-group">
   <h5>Courses <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
   <div class="controls">
     {% for course in courses %}
         <input name="courses" type="checkbox" id="course-{{course.id}}" value="{{course.title}}" required>
         <label for="course-{{course.id}}">{{course.title}}</label>
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
 </div>
```